# Can not delete closed readonly site with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp, office-dev-pnp

I have a site which has site policy associated.

[image]

based on my policy site is closed and marked as read-only.

When I try to delete the site from Admin got an error "Couldn't delete site"

[image]

One of the possible way to delete the site is, first Open the site from Site Closure and Deletion and then delete. Is there any other way I can delete the site without opening?

Is there CSOM API which with which I can open the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete the site I had to first Open the site.

```
    using (ClientContext clientContext = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(url, <ClientID>, <ClientSecret>))
    {
        var web = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        web.SetOpenBySitePolicy();
    }

    using (var clientContext = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(
                                    <TenantAdminUrl>
                                    , <ClientID>
                                    , <ClientSecret>))
    {
        var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);

        var removeSite = tenant.RemoveSite(url);
        clientContext.Load(removeSite);
        clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the site by PowerShell command “Remove-SPOsite”.

There is PowerShell script for your reference.

```
#Variables for processing

$AdminSiteURL = "https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/"

$AdminName = "username@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com"

$SiteCollURL = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/Sales"



#Credentials to connect 

$SecurePWD = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" –asplaintext –force  

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $SecurePWD



#Connect to SharePoint Online

Connect-SPOService -url $AdminSiteURL -credential $Credential



#Delete SharePoint Online Site Collection

Remove-SPOSite -Identity $SiteCollURL -NoWait -Confirm:$false



Write-Host "Site collection has been deleted!"
```

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[SharePoint Online: Delete Site Collection using PowerShell.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/02/delete-site-collection-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html)